# Asset Browser not adding to default location

Tags: collections, asset-browser

I am trying to add my character collection to the asset browser. However when I mark the collection as an asset, it shows up in the local file within the asset browser, but not my default folder. Since its only marked in my local file, I can't bring it to any other files, which is what I'm trying to do. How can I get my asset to show up in the default folder in the asset browser?

Comment: Hello ! The asset browser is not yet officially released and supported, so it is unfortunately out of scope for this site. You can however instead file a bug report explaining your problem if you feel like it's warranted.

Comment: Try this answer which basically helps you to copy your .blend file inside your global path Asset Library: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235002/asset-browser-how-to-make-a-current-file-append-asset-mesh-become-part-of/235015#235015