# Asset Browser - How to make a "current file" (append) asset mesh become part of the "custom default" (windows library folder)?

Tags: file-browser, asset, library, asset-browser

Blender can store assets in a custom folder in your PC using the "Custom / default" path set into File system paths in user Preferences. This library can contain all your assets available for any scene. Hence I will refer to this as the "global library".
Blender also gives you the option to embed your asset library in the current .blend file you're working on. This is the "Built-in / current file" asset library.
Question:
If I open a .blend file with library assets, how can I transfer them to my "global" library? Do I just copy/paste the .blend to the windows folder (custom/default)? If so, how to categorize my assets?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to create a .blend file that already contains the asset library with the assets you need to "append" or (import) to your global path library.
2. In user preferences>file paths> Asset Libraries (Default)>File Path must be defined first.
3. Then, copy your .blend file into that directory (ie.: E:/Blender Asset Main Library).
4. Open Blender, switch to a Library Asset view, click the category (Mesh / shader, etc..) and you should see your Assets from the .blend file into your global Library of Assets for Blender.